# Grails Unique Id constraint in Unit test not failing

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I'm upgrading from grails 1.3.6 to 2.2.4 and going through all of my unit tests.  I have been replacing mockDomain with the @Mock annotation among other things.  One of my tests is validating that IDs remain unique and fail if an id already exists.  This no longer seems to be failing as expected.  The test is as follows:

```
import grails.test.*
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
@Mock(SecurityValue)
@TestFor(SecurityValue)
class SecurityValueTests{
    void testUniqueId() {
        def validEntry = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName",userId:"testUser",componentId:1000)
        validEntry.id = "id"
        def saved = validEntry.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        assertNotNull saved
        def validEntry2 = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName1",userId:"testUser3")
        validEntry2.id = "id"
        def saved2 = validEntry2.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
        def all = SecurityValue.findAll()
        assertNull saved
    }
}
```

Domain:

```
class SecurityValue {

String id
String propertyName
String userId
//String userName
Long componentId

static constraints =
{
    id unique:true, size: 1..100
    propertyName nullable: false, size: 1..100
    userId nullable: false, size: 1..10
    componentId (
        nullable: true, size: 1..10
    )
}

static mapping =
{ 
    table 'pac_sys.security_value'
    id column:'id', type: 'string', generator: 'assigned'
    version false;
}
}
```

The issue I'm getting is that the `validEntry2.save` line is not failing.  I added the `findAll` line to see what data was being stored and it appears that the `validEntry` is just being overwritten by `validEntry2`.

Am I missing a mock statement or something else here?

---

Here is what the test look slike after applying jonnybot's answer.  It now has a shouldFail method rather than an assertNull and works properly.

```
void testUniqueId() {
    def validEntry = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName",userId:"testUser",componentId:1000)
    validEntry.id = "id"
    mockForConstraintsTests(SecurityValue, [validEntry])
    def validEntry2 = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName1",userId:"testUser3")
    validEntry2.id = "id"
    shouldFail(grails.validation.ValidationException)
    {
        def saved2 = validEntry2.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that make sense though? Why would it decide to insert a record when the id that is specified already exists?

Comment: @JamesKleeh Because Joseph said `new SecurityValue()` not `SecurityValue.get()`. What Joseph (rightly) expects to happen is for GORM to refuse to create a new domain class when one with the given id already exists... and it probably would in an integration test. I think Joseph just needs to use the `mockForConstraintsTests()` method. Even back in the 1.3.7 days, mockDomain() did enough to let you test uniqueness constraints, but now that he's removed it he'll need to use the `mockForConstraintsTests()` method to get a unit test that validates constraint rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since what you really want to do is test the constraints, use the mockForConstraintsTests() and validate() methods in your test. See "Testing Constraints" under http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains.

For example, you might have

```
void testUniqueId() {
    def validEntry = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName",userId:"testUser",componentId:1000)
    validEntry.id = "id"
    def saved = validEntry.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    assertNotNull saved
    mockForConstraintsTests(SecurityValue, [validEntry])

    def invalidEntry = new SecurityValue(id:"id",propertyName:"propertyName1",userId:"testUser3")
    invalidEntry.id = "id"
    assert !invalidEntry.validate()
}
```

Comment: This works perfect.  I now get the proper `ValidationException`.